# How to access a variable from other Scope without passing arguments or putting global variables?

Tags: python

I have a function lambda_handler in the lambda module including other module and calling helloWorld function.

Passing the arguments in the helloWorld function or putting the variables as global is not an option. Is it possible to access variables from earlier scope?

```
#--- lambda.py ---   
import my_module 

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    my_module.helloWorld()   

#--- my_module.py ---
def helloWorld():
    local_variable = <something>.context
```

Comment: "Passing the arguments in the helloWorld function is not an option" why? In theory you can mess with the previous frame.

Comment: @DeepSpace passing the arguments in helloWorld function is not an option in this problem since I cannot modify the provided API

Comment: You can't access variables from an inaccessible scope, no - otherwise scope would have no meaning. That doesn't mean you can't design your scopes in the way you need. In this case, while the context isn't totally clear, perhaps you could move `helloWorld` so that it is defined inside `lambda_handler`? (The only reason this wouldn't work would be if you need to access `helloWorld` outside `lambda_handler`.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond It is possible by inspecting the calling frame.

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace - I stand corrected. I still think though that for most uses the kind of introspection you have in your answer is too "magical" for ordinary use, and it's better to simply rethink your program design.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, could you give more infos about this API that prevents you from passing arguments and how exactly it prevents you from passing arguments ?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I agree, which is why I asked OP in the first comment *why* they can't pass arguments. Their answer was enough to justify that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) module to get the calling frame's local variables:

```
import inspect


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    helloWorld()

def helloWorld():
    calling_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    print(calling_frame.f_locals['event'])
    print(calling_frame.f_locals['context'])


lambda_handler('an event', 'a context')
```

Outputs

```
an event
a context
```

Answer (score -2):

You might try:

```
from mymodule import *
```

Because that should import the variables from *mymodule*.

But it might not import variables created after the import, because it reads the code in the *def* statements as what to do when called, it doesn't actually create the variables.